# Reset ownership

Tags: centos, chown

An employee accidental recursively changed permissions from the root directory to *apache*. I reran it to root, we fixed MySQL, but SSH still doesn't work. What is the correct way to restore the ownership for `sshd`?

Comment: You're probably best off restoring from backup. SSH isn't the only thing likely to be affected by this, and getting it back to normal is probably nearly impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to restore the permissions for `sshd` the command would be:

```
rpm --setugids openssh-server
```

From the manual:

> **`rpm --setugids PACKAGE_NAME`**  sets user/group ownership of files in the given package..